# Can C macros be expanded in flex?

Tags: macros, flex-lexer

From what I gather, the following won't work in flex:

```
...
std::string opt_val = "--help";

%%
opt_val { /* do something */ }
%%
```

Can I expand a C macro instead?
I've tried this:

```
%{
#define MCR_OPTION "--help"
%}

ALIAS_OPTION MCR_OPTION

%%
{ALIAS_OPTION} { /* do something */ }
%%
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work.
I want to keep the string literal values someplace else than the rule section of the scanner,
so that if they change, I will have one less place to update.
Am I missing something obvious?

(EDIT): Here is a more complete sample that I tested:

test.l

```
%option noyywrap

%{
#include <iostream>
#define MCR_HELP_OPT "--help"
#define MCR_HELP_OPT2 --help
%}

ALIAS_HELP_OPT MCR_HELP_OPT
ALIAS_HELP_OPT2 MCR_HELP_OPT2

%%
"--works" { std::cout << "this works" << std::endl; }
{ALIAS_HELP_OPT} { std::cout << "help" << std::endl; }
{ALIAS_HELP_OPT2} { std::cout << "help2" << std::endl; }
\n { return 0; }
. { /* consume */ }
%%

int main(int, char**) {
    while (yylex()) {}
}
```

I tested it like so:

```
> flex test.l && c++ lex.yy.c
> echo "--help" | ./a.out
> echo "--works" | ./a.out
this works
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with CSS flexbox layouting. Please make sure to use relevant tags in your question.

Comment: I'm not sure if this will work, but have you tried it without the quotes?

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks like that doesn't work either :(

Comment: Run the preprocessor yourself. Use the `-E` switch of Clang or GCC.

Comment: The first snippet won't work because it's C++ (by default, Flex generates C) and because you forgot `%{` and `%}`. Otherwise, creating a variable is perfectly legal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I decided to use CMake's configure_file functionality;
Here is a minimal working example:

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.25)
project(test)

find_package(FLEX REQUIRED)

set(SCANNER_FLEX ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/test.l)
set(SCANNER_SRC ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/test.cpp)
set(MCR_HELP_OPT "--help")

configure_file(test.l.in ${SCANNER_FLEX} @ONLY)

FLEX_TARGET(scanner ${SCANNER_FLEX} ${SCANNER_SRC})
add_executable(run ${SCANNER_SRC})

target_include_directories(run PRIVATE
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
)
```

test.l.in

```
%option noyywrap

%{
#include <iostream>
%}

%%
@MCR_HELP_OPT@ { std::cout << "help" << std::endl; }
\n { return 0; }
. { /* consume */ }
%%

int main(int, char**) {
    while (yylex()) {}
}
```

Then building and running it:

```
> cmake -B build
> make -C build
> echo "--help" | ./build/run
help
```